# How to test (gmock) when expected result depends on an internal random value?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have the following code:

```
std::string a()
{
    srand(time(0));
    return "file" + std::to_string(rand() % 10);   
}

int b()
{
   std::string filename = a();

   std::ifstream file(filename);
   std::string line;
   while (file >> line)
   {
       if (line == "something") return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I want to use gmock to test function `b`.
I have on my local folder 10 files called "file1", "file2" ... "file10" (each contains either "something" or not) - one of them will be picked for reading...

How can I create such test? the return value of `b` depends on the random number generated at runtime.

Comment: test behavior not internals. If you want to test `b` you could count how often it returns `0` and `1` and that should match the distribution of `"something"` in the files. You will find that it does not match when you call `b` often within a second, due to `a` not really being random. `srand` should be called only once.

Comment: You might rewrite `b` to have a `is_file_contain(const std::filesystem::path&, std::string_view word)` and possibly `int b(IFilenameProvider&)`, so each part should be testable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to mock the random function. You could use:

```
class Rnd
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(value,int());
};

Rnd mockedrandom;

#define rand()  mockedrandom.value()
```

Then do `EXPECT_CALL(mockedrandom,value()).WillOnce(Return(42)).WillOnce(Return(666))`

before calling your code.

You'll need to squeeze the define in your compilation of your code-under-test somewhere.

Comment: The define is needed because you cannot directly mock non-class C functions. So make a class with a method, and bend the rand() call to use that.